# WorksheetFunction.Small: How to define Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to apply the WorksheetFunction.Small on another array as such:

```
ReDim ArrSmall(Iterations, 20)

For l = 1 To Iterations
For k = 1 To 20
ArrSmall(l, k) = WorksheetFunction.Small(ArrResult(l, k), l)
Next k
Next l
```

I know this part: `ArrResult(l,k),` is wrong because it asks for a range instead of a single number which I'm inputting. However, I am unsure how to define the range in the code.

Is this possible or do I have to output the values on a TempSheet, then back into an array? I think a solution is to call the whole column of the array but I do not know how.

EDIT:

I managed to write a dummy code which does exactly what I want but the weird part is when I apply the same to my original code, all the values get mixed up (it literally makes up values AFAIK). See below for code:

```
Sub test()

ReDim ArrTest(10, 1)
ReDim ArrSmall(10, 1)

ArrTest = Range("A1:A10")
For i = 1 To 10
ArrSmall(i, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Small(ArrTest, i)
Cells(i, 2) = ArrTest(i, 1)
Cells(i, 3) = ArrSmall(i, 1)
Next i
```

Trying to clear the whole array before a new loop. Maybe that fixes it...

Comment: I'm looking into `Application.Index` now, maybe a solution.

Comment: The first argument for the `Small` function can be a one dimensional array, or a range.  the `Index` function with a `0` for the row argument would return an entire `column` (or single vector of your array, but using Index in this way may be slower than creating the oneD array -- if it is slow, you'll need to test.

Comment: `ArrSmall(l, k) = WorksheetFunction.Small(Application.Index(ArrResult, 0, k), l)` I have this now but it still returns the 1004 error.

Comment: Check this one out, I think it will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055962/make-it-faster/31056364#31056364

Comment: @HolmesIV I'm not quite sure how that will help me...

Answer (score 2):

If you were looking to take the smallest value of each column (which is the same as `Min`) from say A1:T20 then you could use `TRANPOSE` (to work with columns rather than rows) and then `INDEX` to separate each column, i.e.

The `IF` test is to avoid applying `SMALL` to an empty array (else an error results).

```
Sub B()
Dim ArrSmall(1 To 1, 1 To 20)
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim ArrResult

ArrResult = Application.Transpose([a1:t20].Value2)

For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(ArrResult, 2)
If Application.Count(Application.Index(ArrResult, lngCnt)) > 0 Then _
    ArrSmall(1, lngCnt) = WorksheetFunction.Small(Application.Index(ArrResult, lngCnt), 1)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not looking for the smallest value of each column. I'm looking to sort all columns from a multidimensional array from smallest to biggest. Because I think it's impossible to do this all at once I try to extract each individual column, apply the `WorksheetFunction.Small` on them and then add them back into a new array (seems tedious, but I want to create CDF of them later on). I have figured it out how to do this but the result contains errors. For some reason, the "smalled" values (in ArrSmall) are different than the actual values from ArrResult. I'm trying to recreate the error now.